# TYPO3 Table tx_realurl_pathcache doesn't exist

Tags: typo3-8.x, realurl

I'm working with `TYPO3 8.7.28` on Apache with `PHP 7.2.` installed `realURL` from lower versions to the latest `2.5.0` and I've also updated TYPO3 from v7 to v8 earlier this year.

If I try to delete pages or klicking some Backend modules like "DB check", I'll get this nasty error:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `uid`, `pid` FROM `tx_realurl_pathcache` WHERE `pid` NOT IN (?, ?, ..., ?)' with params [0, 1, 2, 3, 13, 50, 51, 14, 52, 53, 422, 229, 54, 352, 15, 55, 59, 60, 62, 328, 57, 66, 67, ..., 220]: Table 'dbname.tx_realurl_pathcache' doesn't exist | Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException thrown in file typo3_src/typo3_src-8.7.28/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php in line 53. Requested URL: https://www.example.com/typo3/index.php?M=system_dbint&moduleToken=--AnonymizedToken--
```

The table `tx_realurl_pathcache` does not exists. That's for sure. But why has TYPO3 or realURL problems with that?

Maybe I will deactivate and deinstall `realURL` clear caches, compare database and re-install realURL again. Is this a solution?

edit: after an update from realurl the table was renamed, but why did I still get this error?

[image: the table was renamed from realurl]

Comment: Did you read that? https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Upgrading-from-RealURL-1.x-to-RealURL-2.x

Comment: Oh, maybe the problem was known a long time. I always can deinstall realURL clear/compare Database and re-install realURL. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe your configuration is not up to date after the update?**
Clear the system caches  (in the Install-Tool)

**Maybe your database is not correct?**
Use Database Compare in the Install-Tool to verify (and fix), alternative deaktivate and activate an extension as this caches the db-configuration again.
Especially realurl has some problems as the 'Database Compare' might not be able to change the index: remove the index with an appropiate tool and let the index be rebuild by TYPO3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Deinstall `realURL` (not deactivate)!
2. Delete Database Tables (backup before)
3. Re-Install `realURL` again
4. Pray every night that we finally use `TYPO3 9.x` without realURL!

Answer (score 0):

Table `tx_realurl_pathcache` was renamed to `tx_realurl_pathdata` in version 2.1.0 (2016-09):

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/commit/d132e02ed6962841123dff6868c082f73146e641